How to display info on google home/nest display
I have a program on my phone that reads my blood sugar value and send it to a web app I made.
On that page I can see my current values and historical data.
Now I want to punt my blood sugar value on the google nest screen.
And if possible I want to ask google: "hey google, what is blood sugar now?".
Is there an API I can use to put information on a google display?
I searched the internet but couldn't find the right way in.
I prefer to do it with PHP, because my scripts are already in PHP so I only have to use 1 language.
An example of data I want to display on my google display:


Google Nest Hub devices currently don't have an open API for directly pushing information like blood sugar readings to the display. One of the workarounds is to use Google Assistant Routines.
Routines allow you to trigger a series of actions with a single voice command.
You can't directly push data, but you can potentially create a routine that works like this:
When you say "Hey Google, what's my blood sugar now?"
The routine opens a specific webpage on your Nest Hub.
We also suggest you to file a feature request via Google's Public issue tracker for a new device type "smart glucometer". In the ticket explain how you use your glucometer currently and what additional feature you'd like, for example, the ability to display readings on Google Nest Hub and respond to voice queries.
